# Enable to Connect to a RDS AWS instance from my computer with MySQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I'm training of connecto a RDS instance, but it's doesn't connect:

This is the information of my instance:
[image]

These are my input rules:
[image]

Does anybody know, what's happening? I think it's a network problem, this the error message:

[image]

I have modified input rules of security groups and allowed the traffic of anywhere IP but it didn't work.

Comment: Is your RDS instance running in a public or private subnet?

Comment: My RDS instance has one vpc, and 5 associated subnets. I have seen some information a they suggests that I have to modify a subnet and add the ip address of my machine, but I don't know what subnet I have to modify. @OlakunleAbiola